# Using services with lazy loaded modules with providedIn?

Tags: angular

`providedIn: 'root'` is given for using the service in whole app.

`providedIn: UserModule` is given for using the service in a specific module.

How can I use a service when it has to be in multiple lazy loaded modules using providedIn?

Comment: Do want only single instance of the service to be instantiated?

Comment: Angular doesn't care whether you're using the service in 1, 2 or all modules. Just use 'root'.